# Conditional filtering logs in Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, logql

I have a Loki instance connected as data source to Grafana collecting the log records from a web-app. Only some of those logs related with web-server contain `"request_id=XYZ"` and I would like to filter out specific log records using `$request_id` variable.

I can't parse `request_id` directly as a label since not all of the logs contain this key-pair value.

In order to do filtering I make a query like this:

`{compose_project="$var1",host="$var2"} | regexp request=(?P<request_id>(\w+)) | request_id=$request_id`

It works nicely, however when no request_id is passed by the user i.e. `$request_id` variable is empty, I can't see all of the logs. Only the part WITHOUT `request_id` in the text is listed.

In a perfect scenario, without `$request_id` being set I would like to see all of the logs. Now I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow conditionally apply this filter `request_id=$request_id` only when regex matches an occurence of the extracted label in the log? Or is there maybe another way to accomplish this?